# If any two connected subspaces of a family of connected subspaces have nonempty intersection, then the union of the family is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Statement: If $\{C_\alpha\}$ is a family of connected subspaces of a space $X$, any two of which have nonempty intersection, then $\bigcup_\alpha C_\alpha$ is connected.

I read that this is true, but as a counter-example consider the following family of connected subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$: $\{(0, 1), (1, 2], [2, 3)\}$. $(1, 2]$ and $[2, 3)$ have a non-empty intersection, but $(0, 1) \cup (1, 2] \cup [2, 3) = (0, 1) \cup (1, 3)$ is not connected. What gives?

Comment: But $(0,1)\cap (1,2]=\varnothing$? So you don't have for all $C_1,C_2$ that $C_1\cap C_2\ne \varnothing$.

Comment: @jgon Oh, I thought the statement meant only two of the subspaces. It didn't say for all two subspaces so I thought it meant just only pick any two

Comment: ahh well that'll do it. The correct statement is that all pairs have nonempty intersection.

Comment: The word "any" is just too ambiguous ...

Comment: @Hagen: In this construction it can only mean *every* in standard English.